# install tensorflow wheel through requirements.txt

Tags: python, tensorflow, github

I'm working on a project and my processor is old, so I need to install a specific Tensorflow wheel, from here: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.9.0/py39/CPU%2BGPU/cuda117cudnn8sse2

The thing is, I'm not even able to install it using `pip`:

```
pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.9.0/py39/CPU%2BGPU/cuda117cudnn8sse2"
```

which brings:

```
 fatal: remote error:
    is not a valid repository name
```

But what I want to actually achieve is to add it to my requirement.txt, so if someone knows how to achieve that, it'd appreciated

Thanks!

Edit:

after downloading all the files I'm getting this:

[image]

Should I compress these files into a .whl file of my own?

Tried `wheel pack tensorflow` but I'm getting `No .dist-info directories found in tensorflow`. Any ideas?

Comment: you will have to download the files and reconstruct the wheel because it's in multiple 7z parts: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.9.0/py39/CPU%2BGPU/cuda117cudnn8sse2

Comment: thanks @jkr , so after downloading the files if I extract them I get a bunch of .py scripts. Should I take those scripts and put them inside a .whl file somehow? Edited question for clarity

Comment: @JuanC it looks like those archive files are corrupted.  You should contact owner of these files to inform about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should download this .whl file on your local filesystem at first.
Then run command `pip install some-package.whl`

Comment: in this case it's three files, should I download the whole folder?

Comment: yes, take a look at the comment above